# Shift pyspark column value to left by one

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like this:

```
|name|age|height      |weight             
+-------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------------+
|  |Mike       |20|6-7|
```

As you can see the values and the column names are not aligned. For example, "Mike" should be under the column of "name", instead of age.

How can I shift the values to left by one so it can match the column name?
The ideal dataframe looks like:

```
   |name|age|height  |weight             
    +-------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------------+
    | Mike  |20  |6-0|160|
```

Please note that the above data is just an example. In reality I have more than 200 columns and more than 1M rows of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`.toDF`** with new column names by dropping **name column** from the dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('','Mike',20,'6-7',160)],['name','age','height','weight'])
df.show()
#+----+----+------+------+---+
#|name| age|height|weight| _5|
#+----+----+------+------+---+
#|    |Mike|    20|   6-7|160|
#+----+----+------+------+---+

#select all columns except name
df1=df.select(*[i for i in df.columns if i != 'name'])

drop_col=df.columns.pop()
req_cols=[i for i in df.columns if i != drop_col]

df1.toDF(*req_cols).show()
#+----+---+------+------+
#|name|age|height|weight|
#+----+---+------+------+
#|Mike| 20|   6-7|   160|
#+----+---+------+------+
```

**`Using spark.createDataFrame():`**

```
cols=['name','age','height','weight']

spark.createDataFrame(df.select(*[i for i in df.columns if i != 'name']).rdd,cols).show()
#+----+---+------+------+
#|name|age|height|weight|
#+----+---+------+------+
#|Mike| 20|   6-7|   160|
#+----+---+------+------+
```

If you are **creating dataframe** while **`reading a file`** then **define schema** having first column name as `dummy` then once you read the data drop the column using `.drop()` function.

```
spark.read.schema(<struct_type schema>).csv(<path>).drop('<dummy_column_name>')

spark.read.option("header","true").csv(<path>).toDF(<columns_list_with dummy_column>).drop('<dummy_column_name>')
```